# unable to show full image as css background

Tags: html, css

I have a big image which I want to use a background for a div. I want to show complete image without without scalling & cropping. tried this code but its not working. what did I miss here?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {height:100%; overflow-y:hidden;}
.bgimg {
    background-image: url(DSC_0076.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}
    .txt{
        padding-top: 200px;
    padding-right: 100px;

    text-align: right;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bgimg">
    <h1 class="txt">
        Dummy Text
    </h1>
</div>
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
    <footer>
        <p>This site is under construction, please wait for some time for the details.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how its showing up:
[image]

However actual image looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You have to create a `<head> ... </head>` section and place the styles inside.

Comment: Where is the page and where is the image?!

Comment: [Here's a CodePen](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/RNRpMK) showing what your markup should look like for full-screen backgrounds.

Comment: @sємsєм everything is at relatively correct position. image is showing up but its cropped.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS needs some work, because body with 100% height means nothing if the HTML height isn't set. You're basically saying; make my body take up 100% of its container, which is the HTML, but by default HTML is auto and is only big enough to hold the contents, effectively making a 100% height on body worthless unless you specify 100% height on html as well, which takes up the browser window.

Also, the overflow on your body is probably causing the cropping.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

And if you want the background image to show up in its entirety, you need to make the container the same size as the background. A background image will never resize the container that it's set to. Just doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Move all `<style>` tags into a `<head>` tag before the `<body>` tag

Try adding this attribute to bgimg:

```
position: absolute;
```

And if you want the image to appear behind everything add this to bgimg as well:

```
z-index: -1;
```

See it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/prw0pqgf/

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Should display your full background.

Check out the "Play it" on the cover section

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Don't forget to explicitly set the size of the div:

```
width: 1024px;
height: 768px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/29ysobnt/2/

Comment: Try setting the div height/width to the images height/width

Answer (score 0):

To make the background image responsive, divide the height by the width, then set the min-height of the div to the vw percentage of the result.

For example, your image is 1024px x 768px.  768/1024 = 75.  So, add to your styles:

```css
.bgimg {
  min-height: 75vw;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/903q9kzb/2/

Fixed by adding a few size properties to other elements. Important that body, html have their height set `html,body{height: 100%;}`

Remember to always use styles in css files and not directly into the html. It's a bad habit and looks ugly!